# install wordpress in subfolder but accessible from maindomain with working subfolders

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to install a new wordpress instance in a subfolder but make it accessible via my maindomain like www.example.com but its stored in www.example.com/wp/. Thats not a big thing to redirect all traffic to this subfolder, but I want to have all other subfolders to be accessible too. And this where I'm stuck at the moment.

Here is a example of what i mean:

Domaincall -> Folder on the server

Wordpress:

```
www.example.com -> www.example.com/wp/
```

Wordpress Subfolders:

```
www.example.com/wp-includes/ -> www.example.com/wp/wp-includes/
```

Other Subfolders on my Domain:

```
www.example.com/otherfolder/ -> www.example.com/otherfolder/
www.example.com/otherfolder/asd/ -> www.example.com/otherfolder/asd/
www.example.com/testfolder/ -> www.example.com/testfolder/
```

I hope you understand my problem, i just want to have a clean root folder on my ftp.

Comment: I also want this problem to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible to install as you need.

Please check the detailed instructions @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory